# Playing around with mails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I`m trying to create the following feature: You register and receive an email like vouldjeff+ewr@myapp.com and when you send something to this email it automatically appears in something like your wall... So my problem is how to realize the creation of the email and the receiving of the mail itself.
Any ideas?

Comment: My big problem is creating those mail accounts... Or somehow do this with some sort of wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby provides Net/IMAP and Net/POP3 you can use to login into your email account.
[Here's a small tutorial](http://codeclimber.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-ruby-for-imap-with-gmail.html).

**POP3**

```
pop = Net::POP3.new("pop.gmail.com", port)
pop.enable_ssl
pop.start('YourAccount', 'YourPassword') 
if pop.mails.empty?
  puts 'No mail.'
else
  i = 0
  pop.each_mail do |m| 
    File.open("inbox/#{i}", 'w') do |f|
      f.write m.pop
    end
    m.delete
    i += 1
  end
  puts "#{pop.mails.size} mails popped."
end
pop.finish
```

**IMAP**

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'username', 'password')
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(['ALL']).each do |message_id|
  msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
  MailReader.receive(msg)
  imap.store(message_id, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted])
end
imap.expunge()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending E-Mails is simple as pie. Simply have a look at the [ActionMailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). If you also want to receive E-Mail, you should write a daemon that fetches Mails from the mailserver continuously in the **background**.

Here a snippet that fetches Mails via POP:

```
require 'net/pop'

config = {
  :host => "mail.example.com",
  :user => "foobar@example.com",
  :password => "…",
  :port => 110,
  :timeout => 10
}

pop = Net::POP3.new(config[:host])    
pop.start(config[:user], config[:password])    

if pop.mails.empty?
  puts "No mails…"
else
  pop.mails.each do |mail|
    # do stuff with mail
  end
end
```

This is pure Ruby-Code, Rails is not needed for this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other options but that's how we do it:

- Postfix
- Rails Cron Job

Postfix allows you to specify a MySQL table/view to check whether an email address exists or not. You can also define Mail Forwardings.

- Create a DB View to match the requirements on Postfix

  - This View should contain all the email addresses and forward them to a different mail account, like `mailparser`.
- Now your Rails can either

  - use a POP3/IMAP frontend to the mailserver (you should install Dovecot or Courier then) to fetch the mails and process them
  - or go to the place on the disk where all the mails are located (check Postfix config for that) and parse the files as TMail objects and process them.

A different option is to make Postfix call `script/runner` with the Mail data, but rails boot-up can take long and a lot of memory, so I prefer having a Cronjob/Backgroundjob/Worker to do this.

P.S. The Creation of the E-Mail will be done by creating a Model for your Rails app which the View will use as a basis.

Comment: For example I have the domain app.com and I have a standart hosting with rails and etc. My hosting provides me mail server. I just what to receive email something like wildcard... Should I install postfix and other in this case? I hope you understand me!

Comment: I want just to receive email and create mail accounts like vouldjeff+asda@app.com not send email...

Comment: My example runs on a Root Server (where we can install all stuff we want). If you have a "simple" hosting provider you should check for wildcard email addresses and use the methods explained by weppos/Nils). This might cause some issues with email spam, but I doubt that your hosting provider has a solid API to "create email addresses".